# Building a tree structure from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

There is an input JSON as per the below format.

```
var inputJSON = [{
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M1"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M2"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M3"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M4"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test2",
    "Application": "application2",
    "Market": "M5"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test2",
    "Application": "application3",
    "Market": "M5"
}];
```

It should be structured as a tree in below format.

```
var outputJSON = [{
    "test1": {
        "application1": ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"]
    }
}, {
    "test2": {
        "application2": "M5",
        "application3": "M5"
    }
}];
```

**What I have tried so far:**

I am able to achieve the tree format with one kind of `TestScenario` but for multiple code breaks.

**Working code for same kind of TestScenario :**

```js
var defaultArrays = [{
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M1"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M2"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M3"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M4"
}];

var testScenario = [];

for (const data of defaultArrays) {
    if(testScenario.indexOf(data.TestScenario) === -1) {
        testScenario.push(data.TestScenario);
  }
}

var marketArray = [];
var shouldLookLikeThis = [];
var obj = {};
for (const b of defaultArrays) {
    for (const c of testScenario) {
        if (b.TestScenario === c) {
      obj[c] = {};
      obj[c][b.Application] = [];
      }
      if (shouldLookLikeThis.indexOf(obj) === -1) {
        shouldLookLikeThis.push(obj);
      }
    }
    
    for (const c of shouldLookLikeThis) {
      var arr1 = Object.keys(c);
      for (const d of arr1) {
        if (b.TestScenario === d) {
            var arr2 = Object.keys(c[d]);
          for (const e of arr2) {
            if(b.Application === e) {
                            marketArray.push(b.Market);
                c[d][e] = marketArray;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
console.log('shouldLookLikeThis', shouldLookLikeThis);
```

**Not working with multiple TestScenario :**

```js
var defaultArrays = [{
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M1"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M2"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M3"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test1",
"Application": "application1",
"Market": "M4"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test2",
"Application": "application2",
"Market": "M5"
}, {
"TestScenario": "test2",
"Application": "application3",
"Market": "M5"
}];
var testScenario = [];

for (const data of defaultArrays) {
    if(testScenario.indexOf(data.TestScenario) === -1) {
        testScenario.push(data.TestScenario);
  }
}

var marketArray = [];
var shouldLookLikeThis = [];
var obj = {};
for (const b of defaultArrays) {
    for (const c of testScenario) {
        if (b.TestScenario === c) {
      obj[c] = {};
      obj[c][b.Application] = [];
      }
      if (shouldLookLikeThis.indexOf(obj) === -1) {
        shouldLookLikeThis.push(obj);
      }
    }
    
    for (const c of shouldLookLikeThis) {
      var arr1 = Object.keys(c);
      for (const d of arr1) {
        if (b.TestScenario === d) {
            var arr2 = Object.keys(c[d]);
          for (const e of arr2) {
            if(b.Application === e) {
                            marketArray.push(b.Market);
                c[d][e] = marketArray;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
console.log('shouldLookLikeThis', shouldLookLikeThis);
```

Comment: post some code you used becuase I'm not a wizard, or maybe edit your question because it's unclear what do you have and what you want to achieve, and how

Comment: I already put the code that i tried and also i want output JSON structure from input JSON.

Comment: oh sorry didn't see it, thought the last one was only json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to first do the grouping procedure. After this, you could [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the previous result to get your desired structure.

## Example:

```js
var inputJSON = [
  {"TestScenario": "test1", "Application": "application1", "Market": "M1"},
  {"TestScenario": "test1", "Application": "application1", "Market": "M2"},
  {"TestScenario": "test1", "Application": "application1", "Market": "M3"},
  {"TestScenario": "test1", "Application": "application1", "Market": "M4"},
  {"TestScenario": "test2", "Application": "application2", "Market": "M5"},
  {"TestScenario": "test2", "Application": "application3", "Market": "M5"}
];

let res = inputJSON.reduce((acc, {TestScenario, Application, Market}) =>
{
    acc[TestScenario] = acc[TestScenario] || {};
    acc[TestScenario][Application] = acc[TestScenario][Application] || [];
    acc[TestScenario][Application].push(Market);
    return acc;
}, {})

res = Object.entries(res).map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Can you please delete this answer. I want to delete this question but not able to delete due to answers on this.

Comment: @RohitJindal Why you want to delete it, I already spent some time making an answer for this.

Comment: @RohitJindal why do you want to delete your question?  People put their time in, and gave you legit answers to a legit question.  This does not seem to be a fair request, IMHO.  Do you have a very compelling, legit reason to have their contributions erased?

Answer (score 3):

I created an object of different test scenarios, iterated over the input to populate the test scenarios, and then converted the output back into an array per your formatting request.

```js
var inputJSON = [{
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M1"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M2"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M3"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test1",
    "Application": "application1",
    "Market": "M4"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test2",
    "Application": "application2",
    "Market": "M5"
}, {
    "TestScenario": "test2",
    "Application": "application3",
    "Market": "M5"
}];

function convertJson(inp) {
    let out = {};
    
    inp.forEach(function(o) {
       if (!out[o.TestScenario]) {
         out[o.TestScenario] = {};
       }
       
       if (!out[o.TestScenario][o.Application.trim()]) {
         out[o.TestScenario][o.Application.trim()] = [];
       }
       
       out[o.TestScenario][o.Application.trim()].push(o.Market.trim());
       
   });
   
  let outArray = Object.keys(out).map(function(k) {
    let d = {};
    d[k] = out[k];
    
    return d;
  });
  
  return outArray;
}

console.log(convertJson(inputJSON));
```

Comment: Can you please delete this answer. I want to delete this question but not able to delete due to answers on this.

Comment: @RohitJindal why do you want to delete your question?  People put their time in, and gave you legit answers to a legit question.  This does not seem to be a fair request, IMHO.  Do you have a very compelling, legit reason to have their contributions erased?

Comment: Can you please update the JSON in your answer that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @RohitJindal I will update my answer. I'm guessing you included sensitive data in your original request. Please be careful in the future.